# Can I run Xcode on a window machine

Tags: iphone, xcode, windows, macos

I'm new to iPhone programming. Can I run Xcode on windows system? Is it possible to build an iPhone app on windows pc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Xcode only runs on Mac OS X. You'll need to buy a Mac - and a recent one too, because the latest version of Xcode only runs on 10.8 now.

You can use platforms like Monotouch and Unity to develop on Windows, but you'll still need a Mac for simulation/testing and deployment.

Comment: Isn't 4.6 the latest version of Xcode? Runs perfectly fine under 10.7